# How to decide on which bluetooth device I want to recieve incoming call?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

Sounds easy, but not so. My workplace is my car and I go in and out all day. So, I connect my iPhone for handsfree communication via the radio AND a bluetooth in-ear-device. When inside and driving I call and answer calls by radio, when outside (and close to!!) the car I answer by ear. BUT what happens is that the moment the call is connected, the radio takes over and I need to open the phone and toggle back to my ear device. Every time, incoming or outgoing. And it drives me crazy when I have my hands full. 
Does anyone know how to control this?

Comment: I've filed feedback with Apple on this topic.  Normally iOS sets audio to the device you used to answer (e.g. if you push the headset button to answer, then audio goes to the headset.  If you tap the phone to answer then audio is set to the phone, etc.)  I found the (undesirable) behavior where the phone detects a bluetooth device in-range and auto-switches the audio to it.  I can not find a way to disable auto-switching audio ... other than to use control-center to temporarily disable bluetooth.